# Why does "life-saving" have a hyphen?

Tags: adjectives, hyphens, orthography

When I listened to a new program, I heard a word "life-saving" and I thought it was life saving without the hyphen.

> Medical community is outraged after a **life-saving** drugs.

I have seen other forms of words that have a hyphen (-) such as fire-proof and two-seater aircraft. How would I exactly know the words that have a hyphen in to avoid my confusion? Is there any grammatical reason behind this?

Comment: If it's a common word, dictionaries would be your best friends! (For example, [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/lifesaving_1) lists both spellings: **lifesaving** and **life-saving**.)

Comment: That quotation must not be complete. It's certainly not a complete sentence.  And when you say you thought it was life saving without a hyphen, do you mean you thought it ought to be written as two separate words, but you heard it (as if) hyphenated in the program?

Answer (score 1):

A common use of hyphens is with words that form a compound adjective, such as, state-of-the-art, life-saving and so on.

There are, however, many rules when and when not to use hyphens. For example, check out a few from [this link](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp).

> Rule 1. Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a
>   noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a compound
>   adjective.
>
> Examples: an off-campus apartment state-of-the-art design
>
> When a compound adjective follows a noun, a hyphen may or may not be
>   necessary.
>
> Example: The apartment is off campus.
>
> However, some established compound adjectives are always hyphenated.
>   Double-check with a dictionary or online.
>
> Example: The design is state-of-the-art.
>
> Rule 2a. A hyphen is frequently required when forming original
>   compound verbs for vivid writing, humor, or special situations.
>
> Examples: The slacker video-gamed his way through life. Queen Victoria
>   throne-sat for six decades.
>
> Rule 2b. When writing out new, original, or unusual compound nouns,
>   writers should hyphenate whenever doing so avoids confusion.
>
> Examples: I changed my diet and became a no-meater. No-meater is too
>   confusing without the hyphen.
>
> The slacker was a video gamer. Video gamer is clear without a hyphen,
>   although some writers might prefer to hyphenate it.
>
> Writers using familiar compound verbs and nouns should consult a
>   dictionary or look online to decide if these verbs and nouns should be
>   hyphenated.
>
> Rule 3. An often overlooked rule for hyphens: The adverb very and
>   adverbs ending in -ly are not hyphenated.
>
> Incorrect: the very-elegant watch
>
> Incorrect: the finely-tuned watch
>
> This rule applies only to adverbs. The following two sentences are
>   correct because the -ly words are adjectives rather than adverbs:
>
> Correct: the friendly-looking dog
>
> Correct: a family-owned cafe

Here's [another](http://www.grammarmudge.cityslide.com/articles/article/426348/2805.htm).

Comment: That first one is a very helpful link, but I think this answer would be improved if a few of those rules were included in this answer, instead of only at the linked-to website.

Comment: Done. Implemented your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Mamta D's answer (I felt my answer would be too long for a comment), you can turn almost anything into a compound adjective with hyphens, as long as it is a phrase that describes the noun. A common colloquialism in American English is to add "-ass" to an adjective to emphasize the quality of it -- the most common being "bad-ass," "bad" being used as the now-outdated (there's another example for you) slang for "cool" or "tough."

However, as with the "off-campus" example, there are many instances where if the word order is changed, the hyphen is dropped. This is because usually the component words of the compound adjective form a phrase of some kind -- very commonly, a prepositional phrase. The sentence provided in that example is such a case; "off campus" is a prepositional phrase when the word order is changed. "Now outdated" is also a prepositional phrase, if I were to move it:

> Bad is used as in slang for "cool" or "tough," which is now outdated.

Hopefully hyphen rules make more sense for you now.